# Azure Data Lake Child Folder permissions using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-lake

I have Azure Data Lake Gen1 and I am using Powershell scripts to give the access permissions to the folders and the script works fine. With a change in the requirements, I have a few child folders created dynamically under the root folder in the Lake.

Is it possible to automatically propagate the permissions to the child folders created dynamically? I tried to use the below powershell script but unless the child folder already exists the Read,Execute permissions of the root doesn't propagate to the Child folders. 
In the portal I do see an option to apply the parent folder permissions to child folders.Under the Data Lake "Access -> Advanced -> Advanced Access -> Apply folder permissions to sub-folders" Option.

**Powershell code**: $df Is the Data Factory variable

```
Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -Account "xxxx.azuredatalakestore.net" -Id $df.Identity.PrincipalId -Path "/" -Permissions ReadExecute -AceType User -Recurse -Concurrency 128
```

EDIT: Interestingly, if the root folder is created with the Write permissions and the child folders dynamically created they inherit the permissions from the parent. The Read doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Satya,

Default permissions on new files and directories in Azure Data Lake Gen1 works in following way.
When a new file or directory is created under an existing directory, the default ACL on the parent directory determines:

1) A child directory’s default ACL and access ACL.
2) A child file's access ACL (files do not have a default ACL).

So indirectly you need to create a default permission set for a user and group of user's in the ADLS Access list.

and then when you will create a folder and sub folder, default permission set would be applied in the child directory.

For that you can do the following:

[image]

Add a default permission list in the Access control list, all the subfolder would follow the same access hierarchy.

For other example please follow- https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2018/3/17/assigning-data-permissions-for-azure-data-lake-store-part-3

Comment: Thanks Mohit, infact I followed the same article and was able to resolve my issue. Thanks for the sharing the article and I am going to mark your response as the answer.